# Visual Studio Code: Java code does not run at all

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am new to this world of programming.
I started like one week ago so I am a complete noob.
I have written some very basic java code but every time I press "run code" it spits out an error message.

It says "The command "javac" is either typed wrong or could not be found".
"exited with code=1 in 0.015 seconds"

What exactly is the problem and how do I solve it?

My code is free of typos and nothing is shown as wrong or incomplete.

I have tried to correct the java path in settings but that did not change anything at all.

Comment: When it doesn't work manually, when do do "ls" or "dir", you can see a binary named javac in the file system?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not really understand what you mean by that.

Comment: Verify that you really have a binary executable named javac in the file system. Then verify that your path environment variable includes the directory that contains the javac binary.

Comment: How do I verify that? I have the file named "myClass.java" in my path. I "cd" into that path and I type "javac myClass.java" and it outputs the error message shown above.

Comment: You claim you have installed a JDK. *cd* into the directory where you installed it, and check if you find a javac file there. What operating system are you using?

Comment: And honestly: these are really basic facts. Please try to use a search engine first to answer your question. This community is not a free tutor service where people sit down with you and explain you the most basic things. Just put "javac path your-operating-system" onto google and see what it tells you. These are again: super basic things, and there are zillions of sites out there explaining them in great detail. Do not expect the people here to write down the same instructions again, just for you.

Answer (score 2):

The message is clear: VS code does **not** find javac.

It needs javac to *compile* your java source code.

As a start, see if you can do that manually: open a console, "cd" into the directory with the source code, and run `javac WhateverClassYouHave.java` to see if that works.

You might have for example only installed a JRE, not a JDK. Then you have `java` (the Java virtual machine), but not `javac`, the java compiler.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am currently using JDK not JRE. I tried doing it manually as you told me but that does not work either. Just gives me a lot of new error messages that it cannot refer to javac.

Comment: @GlennQuagmire So have you every configured the java environment in your Environment Variables? How did you set it?